# Flexible way to render bubbles-like thumbnails with a shadow in html

Tags: html, canvas, css, svg

Goal: speech-bubble-like thumbnails with a shadow, like this one:

[http://min.us/moStWhsGd http://k.minus.com/jbkSDvCUDvhYcj.jpg](http://k.minus.com/jbkSDvCUDvhYcj.jpg)

Size and shadow are subject to change.

My first idea was of course png overlays, but it lacks flexibility and is also not fun. However, it is always possible as a fallback for old ie-s.

Also thought about rendering the "tail" with rotated div, but matching background in it would be a pita.

What'd be the better way? Canvas or maybe an svg mask? Have little to no exp. with these technologies, so a few tips to start will be very appreciated.

**UPDATE:** Well, that's what I came up with svg after some hours of navigating through the docs and browser inconcistencies:

1. It seems impossible to apply both clipping path and svg filter for shadow to an html element via css, so we have to render the whole story inside an `<svg>`.
2. I found two ways of embedding image into an svg: 1) fiter with `feImage` element 2) `foreignObject` with `img` or `div` with background.

   First method can look e.g. like this

   `<svg filter="url(#dropshadow)">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="120" height="120" filter="url(#imageFilter)" clip-path="url(#clipPath)"/>
   </svg>`

   That will work both in FF and Chrome (I failed to make it work in Opera and didn't try ie9). However with this method image in FF appears to be blurred, at least if resized, and in Chrome it looks lighter (sic!) than the original.

   The need to create a separate filter for each image makes it interesting only from the research point of view.

   Second method can look like this

   `<svg filter="url(#dropshadow)">
   <foreignObject width="140" height="140" clip-path="url(#clipPath)">
           <img src="img/ourImage.png" height="140" />
   </foreignObject>
   </svg>`

   It works flawlessly in FF, but neither Chrome nor Opera can apply clipping path to `foreignObject` (didn't try ie9).
3. Only FF seems to support multiple elements within `clippingPath`: if you add more than one rectangle there Chrome and Opera output something weird. So in order to use the first method in Chrome I had to create a `path` in InkScape, while in FF I managed to create the "bubble" with two rectangles, one big and one small and rotated.

So, the second method appears pretty nice, it is rather flexible and easy to use. If only other browsers than FF would support clipping paths better…

Here are the jsFiddle examples: http://jsfiddle.net/B7593/11/ demonstrates both variants with clipping path combined of 2 rectangles so works only in FF, http://jsfiddle.net/B7593/10/ uses path element generated with InkScape and partially works in Chrome.

**UPDATE2:** Well, shame on me, there is a third and the most appropriate way of embedding images into svg: the [image element](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#ImageElement).

Comment: imo, your best option is a png/gif mask that goes over a regular rectangular image... I don't think HTML/CSS/JS can achieve this effect easily

Comment: @Joseph, in terms of easiness you're definitely right. In fact, that's what I've already done. But 1) if there will be (and I know there will be) a need to change shadow color or blur or whatever then I'll need Photoshoping again and 2) the hacker in me doesn't sleep ;)

Comment: well... best I could come up with requires a lot of hard coding and a mask of the same color as the bg... and it doesn't have a shadow... so in a word "fail", but at least it looks prettyish http://jsfiddle.net/ueSDd/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it as an svg, here's how I'd do that:

- use a raster image for the avatar
- use a clip-path that defines the bubble shape using a path element
- apply the clip-path to the image element
- apply an svg filter to the image element to get the drop shadow

Then reuse the basic setup and just replace the avatar url. It should be fairly straightforward to make a quick prototype using Inkscape or Illustrator.

**Update:**
Here's an [example](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/clippath/clipping-and-filtering.svg) of what I meant.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I came up after some inskaping and reading some svg docs: http://jsfiddle.net/k8ZZs/. However, I can't apply the filter to rendered element. Tried to add "style='filter:url(#dropshadow);" as well as "filter:url(#dropshadow);" to different elements: div, clipPath and path, but none of these worked. Also don't understand how to change the size of the bubble easily.

Comment: Well, [here's a way to somehow combine them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443341/add-filter-to-clipped-element-in-svg-combine-clippath-and-filter-elements/).

Comment: I think using foreignObject for something svg can easily handle is way overkill.

Comment: Well, thanks for the example, now I got it. However defining clipping path this way only worked in Opera for me.

Comment: Right, using g elements in use is not allowed in clipPath, I've updated the example to work in the other browsers too.

Comment: Now it works in FF for me, but not in Chrome (15.0.874.15 dev-m). Seems to be a bug there.

Comment: Yes, Chromium/Skia seems to have some bugs with clipping and masking, see https://twitter.com/#!/dirkschulze/status/106061462992195584.

Answer (score 0):

Do a google search for svg to html converter 0.7
Use the lookup on the converter engine to open the clipart library and do a search on that site on bubble.
Find a generic one and alter it in Inkscape
Convert it to JavaScript
There are more than 3 options.
You now have your speech bubble in pure Raphael.
You can use the bubble and associated shadow anywhere controlling it size dynamically using Raphael scale( x , y )

Comment: Thanks for pointing to Raphael, it is really useful for scaling and otherwise transforming svg. However, it doesn't support clipping paths, so in my case it seems useless.