# Add filter to clipped element in svg (combine clipPath and filter elements)

Tags: html, svg

I wonder if it's possible to apply svg filter to clipped html content. All demos I found have clipping and filtering separate.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/B7593/1/. I want the yellow circle to drop a shadow.

Tried adding `filter=url('#dropshadow')` / `style='filter:url(#dropshadow)'` to `circle` / `clipPath` / `div` elements, but none of these worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can do it the way you're approaching it - even if you could make the shadow a part of the clip, you wouldn't see it when you applied the clip because none of the colour is retained, just the opacity of the pixels is used to determine what shows through.  What will work (in Firefox at least), is to apply both the clip and the filter to content within the SVG like this:

```
<g filter="url(#dropshadow)">
    <foreignObject width="300" height="300" clip-path="url(#c1)">
        <body>
            <div id="target"></div>
        </body>
    </foreignObject>
</g>
```

[Here's a full example](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/B7593/6/).

Comment: That's awesome, thank you! Maybe you can also give a few tips (or at least a google search query) about how to make it work in other svg-enabled browsers?

Comment: Chrome and Opera's support for `clipPath` seems to be somewhat broken at the moment, especially embedded in HTML5 content.  I'm not sure there's much you can do unless you're able to submit patches yourself.

Comment: I've [logged a defect for WebKit](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=68251).